# How to use LocalValueBean in jsp page

Tags: java, struts

I have set certain bean label and bean value in one of my dao class.. 
I have created a list of `LocalValueBean` objects and passed it as a list to jsp..
now here at jsp i need to print the label separately and on hover to the label i need to show the value.. 
i need to extract or to say get those values in jsp directly... 
i have also imported the `org.apache.struts.util.LabelValueBean` in my jsp but still its not working.. please let me know if you any ideas...

Comment: what do you mean by nor working? r you getting any exception or you are unable to display the label or????

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your web-container is unable to find the LabelValueBean.class while compiling the JSP. Post your JSP here and also make sure appropriate struts jar is in the WEB-INF/lib

Comment: hey thanks pangea for your help.. i got the problem solved.. i had made some mistake in notaitions. i corrected it and its working fine now... thanks again..